How to Grant Power Pages Site Access via REST API in Power Automate Without 2FA?
I'm attempting to make a REST API call similar to the manual process in the Power Pages UI (Project -> Security -> Site Visibility -> Grant Site Access -> Add Email Address -> Share). The endpoint I'm trying to access is as follows:
[PATCH] https://org.crm11.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/environmentvariablevalues(dd46583a-c37c-ef11-ac20-0022481aeff5)?$select=value
The request body is:
{   "environmentvariablevalueid": "dd46583a-c37c-ef11-ac20-0022481aeff5",   "value": "@{items('For_each_1')?['id']}" }
I’m using Active Directory OAuth for authentication, but I'm receiving an "Unauthorized" error when attempting to run this flow.
Does anyone know if it's possible to handle this using AD OAuth, or is it necessary to pass an access token? Additionally, is there a way to manage this without requiring 2FA, as 2FA is enabled in my case?
Lastly, are there any alternative REST APIs available that allow granting access to a Power Pages site for a specific email address?
I tried to call a REST API to grant site access to a specific email address in Power Pages. I used Active Directory OAuth for authentication and expected the API call to execute successfully, updating the site visibility as it does when done manually through the Power Pages UI (Security -> Site Visibility -> Grant Site Access). However, I received an 'Unauthorized' error.
I expected that using AD OAuth would be sufficient for authentication. I also tried searching for other ways to grant access via API without using 2FA, as it is enabled in my environment, but haven't found a working solution
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/reference/environmentvariablevalue?view=dataverse-latest
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/security/site-visibility

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
